# October CMS custom database types

Tags: postgresql, postgis, octobercms

I'm using October cms with a PostgreSQL database. I want  to install PostGIS and include the geometry database type  for use in a plugin, can anyone help?

I can install PostGIS and make queries using php and SQL but I can't use it with the October cms schema. I want to create a plugin that can store points, lines, polygons etc... and then display the data using a web mapping library like leaflet or OpenLayers.

I found these but I can't get them to work, can anyone help or walk me through the installation? Thanks

https://github.com/njbarrett/laravel-postgis

https://github.com/shiftonelabs/laravel-nomad

Comment: Or this https://github.com/bosnadev/database

Comment: can you share what error you are facing with your code